# How to calculate total number of unique locations in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/n5jy4ozf/1/

```
window.onload = function (){
    let filHenter = document.getElementById("file");
    filHenter.addEventListener("change", grabFileObject)
}


//Task 2 and Task 3
function grabFileObject(event){
    //Grabs the uploaded file
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let filLeser = new FileReader();

    //Reads the file as text and calls anonymous function on load
    filLeser.readAsText(file);
    filLeser.onload = function (){
        //Splits each line
        const lines = filLeser.result.split("\n");

        //Loop to iterate through each line
        for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++){
            //Splits each line in an element
            lines[i] = lines[i].split(",");
            //Saves elements to an object.
            lines[i] = {Date : lines[i][0],
                        Type : lines[i][1],
                        Location : lines[i][2],
                        Amount : parseFloat(lines[i][3])}
        }
        console.log(lines);
        mainfunction(lines);
    }
}

function mainfunction(array){
    console.log("Total number of locations: ", totalNumberOfLocations(array));
}

// Task 4.1
function totalNumberOfLocations() {
}
```

I have an assignment where I have to read a CSV file in JavaScript and display the data and its statistics. I've managed to finish the part where I have to read the files and save each transaction in an array of objects. My question now is how do I calculate statistics for these transactions.

If I want to calculate the total unique number of locations (non-duplicate) in the list, how would I go about doing this using my the setup I already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to save somewhere all the results to see if its unique or not. For example like this:

```js
const data = [{Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'y'}];

function totalNumberOfLocations(array) {
  const unique = {};
  array.forEach(item => (unique[item.Location] = item));
  // Now in unique object you have all unique fields by Location. You can i.e. return and parse it.
  // To just count it, you can use following
  console.log('length of unique locations is', Object.keys(unique).length);
}

totalNumberOfLocations(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` for unique values, after mapping only the location of the objects. Then you can get the count of unique locations by converting this set back to an array and using `length` property

```
const data = [{Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'y'}];
const getUniqueLocations = data => [...new Set(data.map(i => i.Location))].length;
console.log(getUniqueLocations(data)); // prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

For finding anything unique in an array, I use `filter` and compare the index to `findIndex` (unique by property) or `indexOf` (unique by primitive or object ref) because they return the index of only the first element that matches.

```js
const data = [{Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'x'}, {Location: 'y'}];
const unique = data.filter((obj, index, array) => index === array.findIndex(o => o.Location === obj.Location));
console.log(unique.length); // -> 2
```